# how to test Asyncronous services using robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have been using robot framework for testing my Rest APIs?

But I have no clue if we can test asynchronous services. I started to look for robotframework-async library but still could not figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Robot Framework is able to test asynchronous services. The trick is using wait conditions before your verification.

Try:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Load And Verify Table Data
    Click Button To Load Table
    Verify First Row Details

*** Keywords ***
Click Button To Load Table
    Click Element    ${SOME_BUTTON}
    Wait Until Element Is Enabled   ${SOME_ELEMENT_TO_WAIT_FOR}

Verify First Row Details
    Table Row Should Contain   ${TABLE_LOCATOR}  1   ${SOME TEXT}
```

Or something like that. Just whatever you do, don't use Sleep keywords. You will regret it later.